# Ember Data is not fetching data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am using ember-data and in a simple example of classes and students I have an API that is handling `/classes` and `/classes/:class_id/students`.

The classes API request is made without any problems, but when I try to list the students in the class no API call is made.  Right now I am not manually making an API call in the student route, since I was under the impression that ember-data would make the call based on the model relationship.

#### models/class.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name:         DS.attr('string'),   
  students:     DS.hasMany('student', { async: true }),
});
```

#### models/student.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name:       DS.attr('string'),    
  class:      DS.belongsTo('class', { async: true }),
});
```

#### Adapter

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  needs: ['service:session'],
  host: AppENV.APP.API_URL,
  headers: function() {
    return {
      'accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'x-app-sig': this.get("session.token"),
    };
  }.property("session.token")
});
```

### Updates

#### controllers/class/index.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  // simplified query
  all: function() {
    return this.get('students');
  }
}
```

#### templates/class/index.hbs

```
<div class="panel__master-content">
  <div class="students panel__scrollable">

    {{#each all}}
      {{partial 'partials/student-link'}}
    {{else}}
      No students currently exist  <= what always gets rendered out
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</div>
```

#### router.js

```
this.resource('classes', function() {
  this.resource('class', { path: '/:class_id' }, function() {
    this.resource('student', { path: '/students/:student_id' }, function() {
      // other stuff
    });
  });
});
```

### Update 2

In the ember [relationship docs](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_relationships) it says that it expects that the child ids (student) are returned with the parent.  Is this required?  Is Ember not *smart* enough to make the API request via the parent id?

Comment: Your assumptions seem to be correct.  Can you include your controller/template?

Comment: I added the controller, template and routes.  One thing to keep in mind is that there is never an API call to the classes/:class_id/students url.

Comment: Use links if you want Ember Data to connect to a non-standard url. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24515729/how-to-use-ember-data-with-nested-resources/24517273#24517273